# C# AutoMapperMappingException KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mongodb, exception, automapper

**I am guessing all the info except the exception is extra and barely relevant (and is here for completeness). The question is: What, exactly, is the problem that was encountered based on the exception below?**

I am having trouble understanding an exception message. To the best of my understanding, there was an error mapping `BsonDocument` to `ChildItemViewModel`. `Id`, `Description`, and `SequentialOrgId` were mapped successfully...and then something happened, though these are the only properties. Seems like it's looking for `_id` (a property that doesn't exist) in `cI` (BsonDocument that is being converted to ChildItemViewModel), but I have no idea if that's correct, because it makes no sense.

This is a snippet of code (the mapping) where I BELIEVE this to be happening, but I have no idea since I don't have line numbers.

```
        foreach (BsonDocument cI in childItems)
        {
            ChildItemViewModel childItem = Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, ChildItemViewModel>(cI);
            itemView.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
        }
```

This is the Entity Framework View Model (class):

```
public class ChildItemViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long SequentialOrgId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the source:

[image]

Edit: I have confirmed the ChildItems field to be the source of the problem. If I clear them with the code below, the problem goes away:

```
db.items.update(
   { _id: 1245846 },
   { $set:
      {
            "ChildItems":[], 
            "ChildItemsAmount": NumberInt(0)
      }
   }
)
```

The exception:

```
 {"message":"AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

 Mapping types:
 BsonDocument -> Int64
 MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument -> System.Int64

 Destination path:
 ChildItemViewModel.Id.Id

 Source value:
 { \"Id\" : NumberLong(1245854), \"Description\" : \"Image of Ext USB drive containing backup files labeled \\\"Kevin SomeLastName Backups\\\"\", \"SequentialOrgId\" : NumberLong(189) } ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Element '_id' not found.
    at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.get_Item(String name)
    at lambda_method(Closure , BsonDocument )
    at AutoMapper.Internal.DelegateBasedResolver`2.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    at AutoMapper.NullReferenceExceptionSwallowingResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap)
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
    at API.Classes.Automapper.ItemViewModelConverter.Convert(ResolutionContext resolution)
    at AutoMapper.Internal.MappingExpression`2.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<ConvertUsing>b__0(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ProjectingDeserializer`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.Messages.Encoders.BinaryEncoders.ReplyMessageBinaryEncoder`1.ReadMessage()
    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<ReceiveMessageAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.QueryWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.ServerChannel.<ExecuteProtocolAsync>d__24`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<ExecuteReadOperation>d__35`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluentExtensions.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__f`2.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at API.Controllers.ItemsController.<GetItem>d__2.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}
```

Comment: @drheart, how did you get it into that nice format?

Comment: Instead of using `>`, you use four spaces on the left of each line.

Comment: Oh, so you just got it into code, I see. I didn't realize it would format the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB driver itself is the culprit. When it encounters an Id property, it automatically assumes that it needs to be mapped to a corresponding `_id` field. In order to resolve the problem, you just need to add an attribute telling the driver that you know better than it does:

```
public class ChildItemViewModel
{
    [BsonElement("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long SequentialOrgId { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, it appears that there is also the `[BsonNoId]` attribute as well, which you apply at the class-level:

```
[BsonNoId]
public class ChildItemViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try that as a last resort (it's weird because that prop is nowhere in the db/source).. So, I am correct in that it sees an extra property "_id" coming from the source BsonDocument?

Comment: That seems to be the case. What's strange about that is that MongoDB's automapping should recognize your `Id` field as the BsonId, so perhaps the BsonDocument has both fields? Not sure why that would be the case.

Comment: It definitely doesn't have the _id field in the db, like it normally would for a collection document, since it's a nested doc. Screenshot is the obj which is throwing the exception. I will try that attribute.

Comment: Hmm, the attribute didn't help, I was sure that it would, since it seems like the exact solution to my problem, weird.

Comment: Wait a sec, what does the child BsonDocument look like? Specifically, the one that is attempting to get mapped? It's the one in the exception, right?

Comment: You could try putting the `[BsonId]` attribute over `public long Id { get; set; }`. There might be some confusion in the automapper.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply - I edited my post to answer your question, and then tried the BsonId attribute. The attribute didn't help. The child BsonDocument looks like the screenshot I posted (it's actually the exact one causing the problem). Removing it "fixes" the problem, so I am sure it's the cause.

Comment: The reason I ask about the document is because the attempted path the automapper is trying to map is an `Id` field on the `Id` field: `ChildItemViewModel.Id.Id`. If you were to navigate to the reference in your code on the ChildItemViewModel, are you sure that the class it corresponds to is the one we've both been referencing?

Comment: Nevermind, disregard what I'm saying, I think I found your answer. I'll edit my post.

Comment: The problem was that, for whatever reason (if know why, please tell), it wanted "_id" in the ChildItem, instead of "Id" in terms of the MongoDb ChildItem field name. So it was not finding it (I finally found the solution by comparing to items that did work. Stupid mistake on my part). In either case, thanks again for your time and help - you really helped me narrow it down. (Can't award bounty for another 22 hrs, but it's yours)

Comment: Did you try the `[BsonNoId]` attribute?

Comment: Yes, after I typed the comment above, I understood why it would work, and it did. Ty, learned some useful stuff =)